# My ISP blocks all internet traffic until my bill is paid, but if I use a proxy I can circumvent it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, proxy, openvpn

Alright so I'm having this bizarre situation. I haven't paid the internet bill yet, every time I try to use the internet, my ISP redirects all traffic to their domain (billpay.ispname.com)

Although, for some odd reason I'm able to launch Tor Browser and connect to their proxy servers or whatever and browse the internet, bypassing my ISP's restrictions.

I looked into it further, and I downloaded OpenVPN and connected to a UDP Port 53 proxy, and now I'm able to bypass my ISP and browse the internet... even though my internet is technically shut off.

Any idea on what is going on?

Comment: Your ISP is inept and are either filtering DNS requests or limiting to HTTP/HTTPS based filtering. They *may* still be monitoring or counting data passing through while not actively blocking it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not shut off - if it were shut off you wouldn't even be able to get to your ISP's page, unless they had it cached somewhere locally for you.

They are being relatively generous or perhaps tongue-and-cheek in letting you keep your internet access while not having paid your bill, but I wouldn't expect that to last much longer; it's likely that the only reason they are letting you get that far is because that's probably the easiest way for *you* to actually pay them.

Comment: Of course, once they finally shut it down, you'll have to mail a cheque, or use your phone ;)

Answer (score -1):

Some ISP providers will let you to browse the network still it doesn't mean they are blind and forgot about you, as the moment you signed the contract with them they can see your billing history in their system per each month and they can see your available balance on your account. Some of the ISP have credit feature like in my case if I ran out of account balance my ISP lets me to browse the internet for 30 days more, they won't shut it down right away. These details are usually written in their *Policy & Agreement*.